# Python opening a File within a Zip File

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to open a file with a zip file in python and copy it somewhere else. How do I go about handling the ZIP file open? I can copy and move files fine, it is just getting into the zip file.

File PATH: t:/Test/step1/step2/test.zip/FIL

I have looked at Zipfile docs, but I just can't get this to work right.

zipfile.ZipFile('file_path', 'r')

Comment: *"...  but I just can't get this to work right."* -- if you can show what you tried someone can point you down the right track.

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917284/extract-files-from-zip-without-keeping-the-structure-using-python-zipfile for how to open a zip file using python

Comment: you may also find this helpful http://pymotw.com/2/zipfile/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want to extract a single file from a ZIP archive. Which you do like this:

```
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile('example.zip', 'r') as zf:
    zf.extract(filename)
```

If you want to extract the file to a different directory, specify that in the `path` parameter of [`extract()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile#zipfile.ZipFile.extract).

```
zf.extract(filename, path)
```

Comment: He wants to unzip the file and move it to a different directory, not rewrite the file...

Comment: @Dumbkid_trying Have I interpreted your question correctly?