# Traversing ZIP Files

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

I'm trying to write a little helper application to look up PDFs on our backup server. I work at a local retail chain, and the staff that do our paperwork occasionally need copies of the reports that come in from our stores. It's often enough that I feel it merits a programmatic answer, so I started work on it earlier today, and am quickly up against a wall.

I don't know much about `zipfile.ZipFile`, but what I've learned isn't enough to do what I need to do. In my backup server, I have a set of archives (one for each day we receive files) named `comsMMDDYY.zip` (with `MMDDYY` as the date we process the files, generally Monday-Friday each week). Inside each archive, I have the set of files received from each store on that date, named `SSSSMMDD.ZIP` (`SS` is store number, `MMDD` is the paperwork date those reports represent).

It's quite likely that inside `coms010814.zip` I will have `00010106.ZIP` -- the dates don't correlate, since each store will be working on the previous day's paperwork and we don't pick up their sent data until the next day.

I can manage traversing those zip archives. I built a listcomp that builds a `datetime.date` object for the day I'm looking for and 10 days after it, then check every `comsMMDDYY.zip` archive to see if it contains my requested `com` file, then I extract it.

The problem is that when I extract the `com` file I'm looking for, it extracts to `\\PATH\TO\ARCHIVE\PATH\TO\ARCHIVE\file.zip`. It seems it's keeping its directory structure inside the zip file, and recreating it when I extract it.

I feel like I'm blundering into the XY Problem here, but I can't get to the next step until I get past this portion.

[My code can be found here](http://codepad.org/xPjIaKZi), commented for clarity (I hope). My ultimate goal is to do something like this:

```
OUT: Paperwork date (mm/dd/yyyy):
IN: 12/26/2013

OUT: Store Number:
IN: 1

OUT: Which report would you like to print
OUT: 1. report name
OUT: 2. report name
OUT: ...
OUT: n. report name
IN: 2

OUT > Printer the relevant PDF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent another hour or so researching the issue, and came up with nothing. Returning to my question, I checked the "Related" menu and saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917284/extract-files-from-zip-without-keeping-the-structure-using-python-zipfile?rq=1) which seemed to perfectly address what I wanted to do.

For anyone else coming across this, instead of writing:

```
file = [file for file in zipfilelist.namelist() if file.split('/')[-1] == target]
if file:
    return file
```

and all the other gobbledeegook, I instead did:

```
file = [file for file in zipfilelist.namelist() if file.split('/')[-1] == target]
if file:
    tmp = archive.read(file[0])
    with NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as f:
        f.write(tmp)
        return f.name
```

Note that I had to iterate using a context manager to do this, since I'm exiting early from my loop (and thus can't close the rest of the files), but it was my goal to refactor that at some point anyway. Now I have the file I need in a [`NamedTemporaryFile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile), passed the name back to my `main()` loop, and can operate on it there. When I'm done, I can `os.remove(file)` and all is well with the world.