# Renaming ZipFile in Python

Tags: python, python-zipfile

To rename the one file in a ZipFile that I'm downloading, I do the following:

```
for item in zipfile.infolist():
    old_name =  item.filename
    match = re.search(r'(.*)(.mdb)', item.filename)
    item.filename = "%s_friend%s" % (match.group(1),, match.group(2)) # I should probably be using replace here
    zipfile.extract(old_name, save_dir)
```

However when I want to extract that file and save it into a specific directory, I need to reference the "old_name" and cannot reference the new. Is there a "cleaner" way of both extracting the renamed file? Or is it more pythonic to first extract and then rename the file?

Like the OP of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917284/extract-files-from-zip-without-keeping-the-structure-using-python-zipfile), I run into the same error when referencing the renamed file.

**updated:** This isn't correctly updating the first file. Though it appears to rename the file properly, it output the originally named file.

```
for item in zipfile.infolist():
    old_name =  item.filename
    match = re.search(r'(.*)(.mdb)', item.filename)
    print match.group(1), match.group(2)
    item.filename = "%s_%s%s" % (match.group(1), year, match.group(2))
    print item.filename
zipfile.close()
with ZipFile(curr_zip, 'r') as zpf:
    for item in zpf.infolist():
        zpf.extract(item.filename, save_dir)
```

Comment: Do you want to extract as you are going through each item? Or would it be fine outside the for loop, in another for loop ? If latter, do not extract in the same for loop you are renaming the file in. Instead close the zipfile using zipfile.close() and the reopen it and then extract the files

Answer (score 2):

After testing found that it is not possible to directly rename the file inside a zip folder. All you can do would be to n create a completely new zipfile and add the files back to the new zip file using different name.

Example code for that -

```
source = ZipFile('source.zip', 'r')
target = ZipFile('target.zip', 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED)
for file in source.filelist:
    if not <filename_to_change>:
        target.writestr(file.filename, source.read(file.filename))
    else:
        target.writestr('newfilename', source.read(file.filename))
target.close()
source.close()
```

Comment: i haven't saved the file yet because I'm downloading it directly from a url ... zipfile = ZipFile(StringIO(url.read()))
Do you recommend first saving it, and then renaming it?

Comment: Just save the `StringIO` object in a variable, it contains your full zipfile (in memory) and you can just wrap it in a `ZipFile` again..

Comment: see above. it's not being found when I try to rename it. I get a KeyError

Comment: After doing a lot of testing/researching , I don't think its possible to rename the file inside the zip itself. All you would be able to do is change the directory/filename after extracting it, as you gave in the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917284/extract-files-from-zip-without-keeping-the-structure-using-python-zipfile question.

Comment: How come that a programme like 7-zip allows us to rename a file inside a zip file and there seems to be no Python library that would allow us to do the same?