# How do I to turn my .tar.gz file into a file-like object for shutil.copyfileobj?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gzip, tar, shutil

My goal is to extract a file out of a `.tar.gz` file without also extracting out the sub directories that precede the desired file. I am trying to module my method off this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917284/extract-files-from-zip-without-keeping-the-structure-using-python-zipfile). I already asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37752400/how-do-i-extract-only-the-file-of-a-tar-gz-member/37753786#37753786) of my own but it seemed like the answer I thought would work didn't work fully.

In short, `shutil.copyfileobj` isn't copying the contents of my file.

My code is now:

```
import os
import shutil
import tarfile
import gzip

with tarfile.open('RTLog_20150425T152948.gz', 'r:*') as tar:
    for member in tar.getmembers():
        filename = os.path.basename(member.name)
        if not filename:
            continue

        source = tar.fileobj
        target = open('out', "wb")
        shutil.copyfileobj(source, target)
```

Upon running this code the file `out` was successfully created however, the file was empty. I know that this file I wanted to extract does, in fact, have lots of information (approximately 450 kb). A `print(member.size)` returns `1564197`.

My attempts to solve this were unsuccessful. A `print(type(tar.fileobj))` told me that `tar.fileobj` is a `<gzip _io.BufferedReader name='RTLog_20150425T152948.gz' 0x3669710>`.

Therefore I tried changing `source` to: `source = gzip.open(tar.fileobj)` but this raised the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dzhao\Desktop\123456\444444\blah.py", line 15, in <module>
    shutil.copyfileobj(source, target)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 67, in copyfileobj
    buf = fsrc.read(length)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\gzip.py", line 365, in read
    if not self._read(readsize):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\gzip.py", line 433, in _read
    if not self._read_gzip_header():
  File "C:\Python34\lib\gzip.py", line 297, in _read_gzip_header
    raise OSError('Not a gzipped file')
OSError: Not a gzipped file
```

Why isn't `shutil.copyfileobj` actually copying the contents of the file in the .tar.gz?

Comment: You're missing the size option in `shutil.copyfileobj()`. You should be including `member.size`, else it'll read to the end of the tar file. I doubt it'll fix your actual problem though

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack Oh I didn't realize it read till the end of the tarfile. In this case it isn't a big deal because the tarfile is only one file but jee thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fileobj` isn't a documented property of `TarFile`. It's probably an internal object used to represent the whole tar file, not something specific to the current file.

Use `TarFile.extractfile()` to get a file-like object for a specific member:

```
…
source = tar.extractfile(member)
target = open("out", "wb")
shutil.copyfile(source, target)
```

Comment: `extractfile()` definitely extracts the file but I get the messy subdirs preceding the file. I want to copy only the file and not the subdirs that come with it.

Comment: Huh? Despite the (misleading!) name, `tar.extractfile()` doesn't extract anything on its own. It just returns a file-like object.

Comment: Ok sorry I mistook `extractfile()` to be `extract()` or `extractall()`. I tried your code and it works. While I THOUGHT I read the tarfile docs well enough I clearly did NOT. Thank you!