# extract zip file without folder python

Tags: python

I am currently using extratall function in python to unzip, after unziping it also creates a folder like: myfile.zip  -> myfile/myfile.zip , how do i get rid of myfile flder and just unzip it to the current folder without the folder, is it possible ?

Comment: I'd recommend using `shutil.move`, specify a source directory, and destination (the current), and then `os.rmdir` to delete your temp directory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract files from zip without keeping the structure using python ZipFile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917284/extract-files-from-zip-without-keeping-the-structure-using-python-zipfile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import shutil

# loop over everything in the zip
for name in myzip.namelist():
    # open the entry so we can copy it
    member = myzip.open(name)
    with open(os.path.basename(name), 'wb') as outfile:
        # copy it directly to the output directory,
        # without creating the intermediate directory
        shutil.copyfileobj(member, outfile)
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @heinst.  Luckily Joris already added some comments to the code so you can follow along.

Comment: What do you mean welcome to stack overflow? I was in the Moderator queue and it did not have any comments so I asked you to make some. Dont have to be rude man

Comment: @JohnZwinck ,  currently myzip.namelist() returns,  something like  {folder1/file1.txt, folder1/fil2.txt, folder1/file3.txt} , how could i only return it like {file1.txt, file2.txt, fil3.txt} without the folder directory ?

Comment: @BrookGebremedhin: You use `os.path.basename` for that - I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I use the standard module `zipfile`. There is the method `extract` which provides what I think you want. This method has the optional argument `path` to either extract the content to the current working directory or the the given path

```
import os, zipfile

os.chdir('path/of/my.zip')

with zipfile.ZipFile('my.zip') as Z :
    for elem in Z.namelist() :
        Z.extract(elem, 'path/where/extract/to')
```

If you omit the 'path/where/extract/to' the files from the ZIP-File will be extracted to the directory of the ZIP-File.

Comment: This still extracted the folder when I used the extract() method