# Unzipping a file with subfolders into the same directory without creating an extra folder

Tags: python, unzip, zip

I hope I don't duplicate here, but I didn't find a solution until now since the answers don't include subfolders. I have a zipfile that contains a folder which contains files and subfolders.

I want to extract the files within the folder (`my_folder`) and the subfolder to a specific path: `Users/myuser/Desktop/another` . I want only files and subfolders in the `another dir`. With my current code what happens it that a directory my_folder is created in which my files and subfolders are placed. But I don't want that directory created. This is what I am doing:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile("Users/myuser/Desktop/another/my_file.zip", "r") as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall(Users/myuser/Desktop/another)
```

I tried listing all the zipfiles within the folder and extracting them manually:

```
with ZipFile('Users/myuser/Desktop/another/myfile.zip', 'r') as zipObj:
   # Get a list of all archived file names from the zip
   listOfFileNames = zipObj.namelist()

   for fileName in new_list_of_fn:
       print(fileName)
       zipObj.extract(fileName, 'Users/myuser/Desktop/another/')
```

This yields the same result. I the tried create a new list, stripping the names so that they don't include the name of the folder anymore but then it tells me that there is no item named xyz in the archive.

Finally I leveraged those two questions/code ([extract zip file without folder python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46954626/) and [Extract files from zip without keeping the structure using python ZipFile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917284/)) and this works, **but only if there are no subfolders involved**. If there are subfolders it throws me the error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''`. What I want though is that the files in the subdirectory get extracted to the subdirectory.

I can only use this code if I skip all directories:

```
my_zip = Users/myuser/Desktop/another/myfile.zip
my_dir = Users/myuser/Desktop/another/

 with zipfile.ZipFile(my_zip,  'r') as zip_file:
     for member in zip_file.namelist():
         filename = os.path.basename(member)
         print(filename)

         # skip directories
         if not filename:
             continue

         # copy file (taken from zipfile's extract)
         source = zip_file.open(member)
         target = open(os.path.join(my_dir, filename), "wb")
         with source, target:
             shutil.copyfileobj(source, target)
```

So I am looking for a way to do this which would also extract subdirs to their respective dir. That means I want a structure within /Users/myuser/Desktop/another:

```
-file1
-file2
-file3
...
   - subfolder
       -file1
       -file2 
       -file3
        ...
```

I have the feeling this must be doable with `shututil` but don't really know how....

Is there a way I can do this? Thanks so much for any help. Very much appreciated.

Comment: If this is still a question of interest, I am happy to help answer it, but I am a little confused what you are asking for.  Can you simplify your question?  At the end, you show the structure that you *want*.  Can you also show the structure you *currently get*?  It is not clear what your problem is.