# How to unzip all files from the same filetype with python

Tags: python, unzip, zip, file-type

I want to extract all files that have the same filetype from a zip file.
I have this code:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

counter = 0
with ZipFile('Video.zip', 'r') as zipObject:
    listOfFileNames = zipObject.namelist()
    for fileName in listOfFileNames:
        if fileName.endswith('.MXF'):
            zipObject.extract(fileName, 'Greenscreen')
            print('File ' + str(counter) + ' extracted')
            counter += 1
    print('All ' + str(counter) + ' files extraced')
```

The problem is that the zip file also has multiple sub-folders with the required .MXF files in them.
Thus after running the script my Greenscreen folder also shows all sub-folders like this:

[image]

But i just need the files of the same file-type. So it should look like this:
[image]

Comment: So your code does only extract files with .MXF, and your question is 'how to extract them into one folder and not into sub-folders?'

Comment: Yes. All .MXF fiels are in sub-folders in the zip. After running the script the sub-folders are still persistent.

Comment: I think this will answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917284/extract-files-from-zip-without-keeping-the-structure-using-python-zipfile